# Batch file to switch from domain to workgroup, and back, without using netdom?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dns, workgroup

Is there a way to write a batch file which allows me to switch from a domain to a workgroup, and back again without using netdom, on a Windows 7 machine?? I can not seem to find an answer for this anywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. This is doable with Powershell but again, SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my Google search found.

```
wmic.exe /interactive:off ComputerSystem Where name="%computername%" call JoinDomainOrWorkgroup FJoinOptions=3 Name="myDom.local" UserName="myDom\UsrName" Password="@passwrd!@" AccountOU="OU=MyClients;OU=MyOrg;DC=myDom;DC=local"
```